# How to check if a value is an integer in Javascript (special case 1.0 should be float)

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point, integer, typechecking

I am writing some type check functions. I want:

- isInteger
- isFloat

While writing isInteger, I noticed that isInteger(1.0) returns true. I want this to return false.

My function is like this:

```
function isInteger(value) {
    return typeof value === 'number' && value % 1 === 0;
}
```

I also noticed that it return true for 1.0 because the argument 'value' is immediately converted to 1 (which I don't want).

I did this:

```
function isInteger(value) {
    console.log(value)          // It prints 1 if value is 1.0
    return typeof value === 'number' && value % 1 === 0;
}
```

Of course, I consider the situation where I might need to use regEx:

```
var regEx = /^-?[0-9]+$/;
regEx.test(value)
```

BUT, first I need the function to actually test the value 1.0 instead of 1.

How could I do this in order to maintain the 1.0 in the function argument?

Thank you

Comment: in JavaScript `1.0` and `1` are completely equal.

Comment: use a lookahead to check whether the number contains a dot or not.

Comment: @AvinashRaj this wouldn't work, because `(1.0).toString() === "1"`

Comment: Reopened. Not because it's interesting, it's not. But it's just not a duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you type

```
var a = 1;
var b = 1.0;
```

`a` and `b` are stored exactly the same way. There's **no** difference. That's because there's only one storage type for numbers in JavaScript, it's [IEEE754 double precision floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

If you want to keep them different, don't use the number format, you may keep them as strings for example.

Comment: Hi @dystroy, it's what I thought. If I really need 1.0 to be recognized as float, I have to keep the value as a string. For now, I'll let this go. Thanks

Comment: @joaorodr84 no, that is incorrect. All number values are floats. There are no integer values in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

check for a remainder when dividing by 1:

```
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}
```

Comment: And do you think that would differentiate 1.0 and 1 ?